# Flex datagrids - Alternatives in non-flex/flash environment?

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, jquery-ui, datagrid, extjs

I did some work that used Flex datagrids previously. It was smooth for the users and developers alike.

In my current project, I have to implement the same grids but not using Flex / Flash.

I have taken a look at extJS and YUI but they don't seem to measure up.

Are there other packages I should be looking at ?

Answer (score 1):

What is it that you find lacking with the ExtJs Grid components? I've worked with both Flex and ExtJs, and find them both to be extremely similar. Is there something in particular that you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

For small plugins/libraries, check out the posts on ajaxian.com and ajax rain:

http://ajaxian.com/

http://www.ajaxrain.com

Also the plugin directory for jQuery is pretty rich:

http://plugins.jquery.com/

If you are willing to pay and use .Net, I recommend the telerik suite:

http://www.telerik.com

Answer (score 0):

Must use DHTML trash?  AJAX trash too?  Then you should give up and quit your job.  Why take a step backwards into legacy technology?